# Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After implementing `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to my project I was getting an error during a run time **Failed to merge manifest**, so I migrate my app to `Androidx`. After migrating to androidx I'm getting this error

> "Cannot specify -processorpath or --processor-path via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`. Use the `CompileOptions.annotationProcessorPath` property instead."

My build.gradle(Module: app) file

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),            
       'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
      }
    }

dependencies {
   implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0')  
   {force= true}
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.1.0',   
   {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

    // Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider
    apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
    implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'

    // Preferences Dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: may be the problem is in this line 'exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' remove this line and try to sync.
'

Comment: @TakeInfo still getting the same error on runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here.Remove this line from code.

> apply plugin: 'android-apt'

And use only this plugin.

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

From Android Gradle plugin version 2.2 or above android-apt is deprecated for this versions and all functionality that was previously provided by android-apt is now available in the Android plugin. You can read more about this from [here](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration).